# How to get SelectedValue from CombBox with AutoComplete?

Tags: c#, winforms

Normally I fill comoboBox this way :

```
combo.DataSource = dt;
combo.ValueMember = "id";
combo.DisplayMember = "name";
```

and easily I can get selected value with this code

```
int i = convert.toint(combo.selectedValue);
```

but after I use AutoComplete I can't get it:

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ACDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name from usersTBL", con);
da.Fill(dt);
AutoCompleteStringCollection datasource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  datasource.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
this.comboSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = datasource;
this.comboSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
this.comboSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.comboSearch.DataSource = dt;
this.comboSearch.DisplayMember = "name";
this.comboSearch.ValueMember= "id";
```

Now if I select an item from the comboBox manually, I can get the SelectedValue, but if I use auto complete, I can't. I want to get SelectedValue when I search for Selected item from the ComboBox.

Comment: yes i did that but in my code , its my write error only

Comment: *When* are you checking the SelectedValue property?

Comment: Have you tried `comboSearch.Text` ?

Comment: int i = convert.toint(combo.selectedValue);
i need selected value (id) when i type the name in th combox

Comment: The code you posted doesn't duplicate the problem.  When I use SelectedValue, it works.

Comment: try to search for any name when it autocompleted try to get id from combo.selectedValue , it's equal to null

Answer (score 1):

now it work fine

```
public frm_order()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        AutoCompleteStringCollection farmerdatasource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < farmer.GET_FARMER_NAME_HAVE_PRODUCT().Rows.Count;i++ ) {
            farmerdatasource.Add(farmer.GET_FARMER_NAME_HAVE_PRODUCT().Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
        this.farmerNameCmb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = farmerdatasource;
        this.farmerNameCmb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.farmerNameCmb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;




    }
```

and in FORM_LOAD i fill combobox :

```
this.farmerNameCmb.DataSource = farmer.GET_FARMER_NAME_HAVE_PRODUCT();
            this.farmerNameCmb.DisplayMember = "farmerName";
            this.farmerNameCmb.ValueMember = "farmerID";
```

Now i can search in my comboBox and get the ValuMember easly